# SQuirreL add new driver occurs ERROR slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: squirrel-sql, clickhouse

Just installed SQuirreL 3.8.1

And trying to add new jdbc driver
[image]

And then after I click Ok button
I see this one
[image]

squirrel error log

```
2018-02-01 15:31:41,420 [AWT-EventQueue-1] ERROR net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Application  - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

What I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try install jdbc driver over maven
your squirrel installation don't see other yandex jdbc dependencies

see all here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ru.yandex.clickhouse/clickhouse-jdbc/0.1.36

aslo you can try compile jar with dependencies itself use following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/yandex/clickhouse-jdbc.git
cd clickhouse-jdbc
mvn package assembly:single -DskipTests=true
```